# InflateException at spefic case, what am I missing?

Tags: android, android-inflate

I'm receiving an InflateException from ChatActivity when it is not the LAUNCHER activity but when I change the manifest such that ChatActivity is the LAUNCHER, the app work properly.
I'm probably missing something, is there something missing in the code?

**Update 18:15 16.10** -
I've found that if I delete

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

from LoginActivity the app working (but now I don't have buttons).
What is the cause of this problem and how can it be fixed?

Part of the MANIFEST when the error accrue -

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ChatMainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity" />
```

And if I'm changing the file to this (below) the chat work properly -

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ChatMainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity" />
```

The dependencies -

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

XML file of ChatActivity -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ChatMainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"></com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tabPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity -

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.nirkov.hive.Fragments.ChatFragment;
import com.nirkov.hive.Fragments.ChatOffersFragment;
import com.nirkov.hive.Fragments.ChatRequestsFragment;
import com.nirkov.hive.R;

public class ChatMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chat");

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_bar_layout, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new ChatRequestsFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ChatFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ChatOffersFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position){

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return "REQUESTS";
            case 1:
                return "CHATS";
            case 2:
                return "OFFERS";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The appTheme style -

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The LoginActivity -

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.nirkov.hive.R;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

private Button   loginButton;
private EditText emailBox, passwordBox;
private TextView registerHereLink;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton      = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    emailBox         = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailBox);
    passwordBox      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordBox);
    registerHereLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerHereLink);

    progressBar      = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loginProgressBar);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    registerHereLink.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ChatMainActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.loginButton:
            String email    = emailBox.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordBox.getText().toString();

            loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            signIn(email, password);
            break;

        case R.id.registerHereLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}

private void signIn(String email, final String password){
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
            addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "signIn : success");
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }else{
                        Log.w(TAG, "signIn:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
}
}
```

The Login XML file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activities.LoginActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="255dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Email:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

<!--Password : text view and text box-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Password:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailBox" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordBox" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loginProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spaceInBottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/loginButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/loginButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/loginButton" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registerHereLink"
    android:layout_width="63dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Register Here"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginButton" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The full error -

```
2019-10-16 01:07:43.323 6109-6109/com.nirkov.hive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nirkov.hive, PID: 6109
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nirkov.hive/com.nirkov.hive.Activities.ChatMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.nirkov.hive-8a2GYMMALuvTn0Up_KEgfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nirkov.hive-8a2GYMMALuvTn0Up_KEgfw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.nirkov.hive.Activities.ChatMainActivity.onCreate(ChatMainActivity.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: can you post your AppTheme style ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post. @SebastienRieu

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I added it @paxcow

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); There is no **MainActivity** in your Manifest. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

upload login Activity code as well , and tell me which is your parent class

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to your main style and see if that works?

Comment: The error is odd, it says `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` but, your dependencies are material design library and android x. Can you make sure that you do not have any imports of android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout anywhere in your project? Also perhaps if you changed these, cleaning and re building the app might solve the problem too, if you havent already tried that

Comment: I've tried to search after android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout in all files through the android studio search and I did not find anything

Answer (score 0):

`Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" on path`
 Comes from your activity where you set the toolbar wrongly:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Your toolbar is wrapped by `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`.

So there's no need to add it into the supportActionBar.
Just define your activity theme as `NoActionBar` (in your styles.xml) and delete `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` in your activity